# How to Pass values in webservice url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services

I have a problem when I pass data to a web service url. Here is my code :

```
var medical = $("#medicalid").val();
var password = $("#password-field").val();

$("#login").click(function () {
    var url = "http://41.128.183.109:9090/api/Data/getloginer?medid=" + medical.toString() + "&pass=" + password.toString() + "";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'Get',
        success: function (data) {
            if (JSON.stringify(data) != "[]") {
                window.location.href = "../maps.html";
            }
            else {
                alert("Please make sure for you data !");
            }
        },
    });
});
```

I want to make login page with id and password. `medicalid` and `password` are inputs fields. When I use a url as `http://10.1.1.29:9090/api/Data/getloginer?medid=a&pass=a` it works fine but when I replace the values of my input fields it doesn't work. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: DONT put user name and passwords in URLs, always a bad idea. Said that, you are not URL encoding (use encodeURIComponent() API) the parameters, which could be breaking the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the values of your `input` elements *inside* the click handler. Currently your code is retrieving the value on load before the user has typed anything in to them. Try this:

```
$("#login").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://41.128.183.109:9090/api/Data/getloginer',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            medid: $("#medicalid").val(),
            pass: $("#password-field").val();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (JSON.stringify(data) != "[]") {
                window.location.href = "../maps.html";
            }
            else {
                alert("Please make sure for you data !");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Note I amended the logic slightly so that the values are provided via the `data` parameter of `$.ajax`. This is to ensure they are encoded correctly for use in a querystring.